# php replace comma at the end of word that ends with lowercase letter to a colon

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I have a string like this: `2D-Digital, 1:10PM, 3:10PM, RealD-3D, 5:15PM` What I need is a string like this `2D-Digital: 1:10PM, 3:10PM, RealD-3D: 5:15PM`

I thought about using preg_replace on the string to find the words that end with a letter and then replace the `,` into a `:` but the problem with that is the 3:10PM and such also end with a letter. Please help me.

Comment: add some look-around assertions to check for `pm` and `am`?

Comment: The title of this question is incorrect given your examples `RealD-3D, 5:15PM` -> `RealD-3D: 5:15PM`.

Comment: sorry @chris85 didn't realize that

Comment: I'd update the samples or the title so you get correct responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative and positive look-behind to find the desire commas :

```
(?<![AP]M)(?<=[a-zA-Z]),
```

see demo https://regex101.com/r/hD7bE6/2

Comment: It should probably be `(?<![AP]M)(?<=[a-zA-Z])` since PM could be AM.